# Liapunov's Function and kind of Stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

**Problem :**

> Using the right Liapunov's Function V find the kind of stability of the non-linear system:
>   $$ x'=\sin(x+y) $$
>
> $$y'=-\sin(x-y)$$
>
> given the Liapunov's function: $$V=x\cdot y $$

So, I don't have any experience on this type of exercices and I don't know even how to start the exercice.I know that i have to differentiate  the liapunov's function $$V=x\cdot y$$ so i take :$$V'=Vx\cdot x'+Vy\cdot y'$$ but i don't find the reason and i don't know if it's right too.

I would really appreciate a thorough solution and explanation, since I've just started working on Liapunov's functions and Liapunov's stability and I have to clear my mind on them.I have to say that my dynamical's system book doesn't have problems of these types so to proceed.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stability at which point? At (0,0)?

Comment: yeah,maybe.I have translated exactly what my problem says.I think that we have to work at (0,0).

Comment: Do you know that a Lyapunov function must be positive semi definite in a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ if you want to prove stability for $(0,0)$? The function you suggest is not positive semi definite.

Comment: no this is something new for me.I have attended all the lectures but our professon haven't talked about this.So,it's something that helps me.generally,he prefers to show as some theoritical problems and that's why i have no experience with this problems.

Comment: Then I would suggest to look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function

Comment: And tell me if you understand why the $V$ you have is not positive semi definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the $V$ you mentioned is not a Lyapunov function. Define the Lyapunov function $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. It is an exercise for you to verify that this is indeed a Lyapunov function for determining the stability of the point $(0,0)$.

If we consider $V(x(t),y(t))$ then this function is a function of $t$. Moreover the derivative w.r.t. $t$ is $\dot V(x(t),y(t))= \partial _x V(x(t),y(t))\cdot x'(t)+\partial_y V(x(t),y(t)) \cdot y'(t)$. Lyapunov's second theorem about stability is the following.

> **Theorem** (Lyapunov's second method). Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a neighbourhood of the origin. Let $V:U\to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lyapunov function. Then the following is true:
>
> - If $\dot V \leq 0$ on $U\setminus \textbf{0}$, then $\textbf{0}$ is stable.
> - If $\dot V < 0$ on $U\setminus \textbf{0}$, then $\textbf{0}$ is asymptotic stable.
> - If $\dot V > 0$ on $U\setminus \textbf{0}$, then $\textbf{0}$ is unstable.

Let's go back to our $V$ that we have defined there. We calculate the derivative w.r.t. $t$ but do not use $t$ in our notation because that makes it a little bit messy. We just write $x$ instead of $x(t)$. 
\begin{align}
\dot V(x,y) &= 2x \cdot x'+2y \cdot y'\\
&= 2x \sin(x+y)  - 2y\sin(x-y)
\end{align}
Now we must find out what the sign is of this expression in a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$. A natural thing to do is to take the Taylorpolynomial of the sine function around zero, so:
\begin{align}
\dot V(x,y) = 2x(x+y) -2y(x-y) + O(||(x,y)||^3) = 2x^2+2y^2 + O(||(x,y)||^3)
\end{align}
Since $O(||(x,y)||^3)$ has a much smaller magnitude than $2x^2+2y^2$ around $(x,y)=(0,0)$ we can actually find a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ where $\dot V$ is positive in that neighbourhood excluding $(0,0)$. So $(0,0)$ is an unstable stationary point of the given differential equation.

Comment: Τhis is a very good answer to my problem.The only thing that i didn't understand is how you chose this liapunov's function $$V=x^2+y^2 $$ for this problem and why?And why my problem gives me $$V=x\cdot y $$ if it's not a liapunov's function?How can i use it to solve these type of problems?

Comment: I really do not understand why they give you that function. And my choice of $V$ is one of the standard choices for a Lyapunov functions. To get a feeling for it, you need to exercise many times with these kind of problems. I hope this helped.

Comment: Yeah,you helped me a lot with this.Thanks,a lot.I have to find why they give me this V function!

Answer (score 1):

You should take the gradient of the Liapunov function
$$\nabla V = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} V, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} V\right)$$
and consider what angle this makes with the vector field of the given differential equation.

Can you show the cosine of this angle is always positive or always negative, in certain regions of the plane?
This will tell you something about how the trajectory specified by the differential equation will be constrained by the level sets of the Liapunov function $V(x,y) = c$.

Comment: It's the first time that i hear about the gradient of liapunov.I am not sure that i understand your answer.Can you clarify what do you mean when you say ,that i have to find what angle make the grad liapunov with the vector field of the given differential equation?

Comment: The idea I had in mind is described in definition 2.6 [here](https://users.ece.utexas.edu/~nikolova/papers/essay1.pdf). Does that make sense? I can try to elaborate more.

Comment: Could you elaborate  more please?I am sorry but i have problem with this $$V=x\cdot y $$ function as it's not a liapunov function and maybe your solution can save me.

Comment: I think there may be a mistake in the problem-- either the Liapunov function should be $V = x^2 + y^2$ as Shashi suggested, or there was a mistake in the differential equation. If we had $y' = \sin(x-y)$ instead of negative, then $V = xy$ would be a valid Liapunov function.

Comment: are you sure you have the signs right in $x'$ and $y'$?

Comment: yeah,for sure!Maybe in this exercise ,i have to prove that V is not a Liap Function and take another V function by myself but it's something that will be strange as the exercise is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Set $V(x,y)=\sin^2(\frac{x+y}2)+\sin^2(\frac{x-y}2)$ then
\begin{align}
(\dot V f)(x,y)&=(\sin(x+y)+\sin(x-y))\sin(x+y)-(\sin(x+y)-\sin(x-y))\sin(x-y)
\\
&=\sin^2(x+y)+\sin^2(x-y)
\end{align}
which shows that the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is unstable.

---

Using the half-angle formulas one can further transform
\begin{align}
(\dot V f)(x,y)&=4V(x,y)-4\sin^4(\frac{x+y}2)-4\sin^4(\frac{x-y}2)
\\
&=4V(x,y)-2V(x,y)^2-2\left(\sin^2(\frac{x+y}2)-\sin^2(\frac{x-y}2)\right)^2
\end{align}